# jQuery store effect name in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

I'm searching for a couple of weeks to do this trick with jquery but everything failed so I'm posting it here.

Is it possible to store an effect name in a variable and then execute that effect on a div?

I mean something like this:

```
var effect = 'fadeOut';

$('#some_div').effect();
```

I hope you will understand what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var effect = 'fadeOut';

var $div = $('#some_div');
$div[effect]();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets for the property access. Methods in JavaScript are properties too.

```
$('#some_div')[effect]();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation:

```
$('#some_div')[effect]();
```

This will run the function with the name equal to the value of `effect`.